# How distribute the bandwidth usage on my drupal site?

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, centos7

I have a drupal commerce website at where users upload a lot of files all the time. Then, my critical resource is the bandwidth.

Since the servers have a limited bandwidth, I would like distribute these uploads on multiple servers running the same site and connected with an unique database.

I think that I can create some subdomains and assign each to one server.

The problem is that I don't know how assosiate each session to one of these servers and avoid users switch to the main server again (intentionally or not) and lose their sessions...

I think I can't add a load balancer in front of these servers since the balancer will receive all request then the bandwidth usage will not be distributed.

I would like know how to handle it.

Comment: Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46764591/how-to-balance-webserver-bandwith-usage

Answer (score 0):

Bandwidth is the cheapest resource in hosting. Having a load balancer, and Drupal behind with many VPS separate doesn't seem to be the best way to do it.

You will spend time configuring, running and mantaining that solution and also spend money. I suggest you instead to spend that money on bandwidth.

Also to save some bandwith, you can configure a service as Cloudflare, which has a free tier, or a CDN of your preference.

Hope that helps.